# Unhandled Exception when using abstract function

Tags: c++, opengl, virtual-functions

I'm trying to load in a basic shader using within my program, but after it's loaded, I get an Unhandled Exception popup box. I've created a base class to do all the common parts of loading a generic shader. within the base class, I have a protected virtual function and public function for handling OpenGL attributes. Here are two basic examples of what's going on:

```
class ShaderProgram // Base class
{
    public:
    ...

    protected:
        void bindAttribute(GLuint attribNumber, const char* variableName);
        virtual void bindAttributes() = 0; // needed for different shaders

    private:
        GLuint programID;
        void loadShaders(const char* vertFile, const char* fragFile);
}


class BasicShader : public ShaderProgram // derived class
{
    public:
    ...
    protected:
    void bindAttributes() { bindAttribute(0, "position"); }
    ...
}
```

Now within `loadShaders()`:

```
programID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
glLinkProgram(programID);
bindAttributes(); // Unhandled Exception pointing here
```

I get this error when I try to run it. but if I replace `bindAttributes()` with `glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "position")` which is called within `bindAttribute()`, the program runs as it should. Any ideas as to what is causing this error?

Comment: you don't call loadShaders() from the constructor, do you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that `loadShaders()` is private to `ShaderProgram`.  With the symptoms and workaround you describe, I suspect you to call it from the constructor of the class.

If this is the case, it's due to the use of the pure virtual function during the construction. More concretely, the construction process of class `BasicShader` derived  from the base `ShaderProgram` works like this:

- first the base object of class `ShaderProgram` is constructed.  At this time the object is only a `ShaderProgramm`.  Virtual 
  functions you may call in its constructor are still those as defined in the base class.
- then the derived object is constructed on the top of the base object.  Only when you enter the constructor of the derived object, the 
  virtual functions of `BasicShader` will be in force.

So if you call `loadShaders()` from the constructor of `ShaderProgramm`, it will end-up trying to call `bindAttributes()` at a moment it is still a pure virtual function (i.e. undefined).

> Standard 10.4/6:  Member functions can be called from a constructor
>   (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making a virtual
>   call to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object
>   being created (or destroyed) from such a constructor (or destructor)
>   **is undefined.**

There are two solutions for that:

1. you call `loadShaders()` from the constructor of `BasicShader` and not of `ShaderProgram`. This requires that you make the function protected instead of private.
2. you change your class logic, and force a load/initialisation phase distinct from the construction process.

*If my assumption is wrong and you don't call `loadShaders()` from the constructor, please post the code where you call it, as well as the initialisation of its arguments,  and I'll update the answer.*

Comment: You we right about where I was calling loadShaders. I moved it to BasicShader's constructor and now everything is happy.